# connection between Web Parts slow page view

Tags: 2007, web-part, sharepoint-server

i have a page that displaying 5 wep part (some of them are hidden)
the are a connection between the Web Parts.

problem is when you cliking on any link to get the view
it is loading very slow (2 min) and some time i get timeout
please anyone have any idease ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out where your web part performance bottleneck lies. Then, see what you can do to address the issue.

Since you're using SharePoint 2007 you don't have access to the developer dashboard (released in 2010).

Here's a decent article that explains some performance troubleshooting techniques for SP2007 (web parts performance too):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.08.insidesharepoint.aspx

Comment: thank for answr boreal , i now that they using some costume default list view (xsltlistviewwebpart) change , is it can by realte ?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad my answer helped. Yes, the performance issues are likely related to custom web parts. Take some time to troubleshoot and if you need further help with specific issue, post a new question.